# Inserting a node into a linked list in ascending order

Tags: c, insert, linked-list

I have a linked list in ascending order, and in some code I will be generating a new node and taking the first two out and need to insert it into the correct place in the linked list. My code below is attempting to do this, so I should be getting print statements saying `list is now 5 nodes long` `list is now 4 nodes long` `list is now 3 nodes long` etc.

At the start temp is pointing at the first node in the list. My logic is that when it finds temp -> next -> frequency to be bigger/equal, it will point the parent_node -> next at temp -> next (the equal/bigger one), and point temp -> next at the parent node, thus inserting the node into the list. However this doesn't seem to be working.

```
while (ind == 0)
{
    temp = temp -> next;
    if (temp -> next -> frequency >= parent_node -> frequency && temp != NULL)
    {
        parent_node -> next = temp -> next; /* parent points at bigger value */
        temp -> next = parent_node; /* temp points at parent */
        ind = 1;
    }
}

temp =  list -> start; /* point list back at start */
while (temp != NULL)
{
    temp = temp -> next; /* run through list */
    counter++;
    printf("The linked list is now: %d nodes long\n", counter);
}
```

It will print the list is now 1 -> 10 long, now 1 -> 9 long, now 1 -> 8 long.

Comment: How does code "know" `temp` and `temp->next` are not `NULL` with `while (ind == 0) { temp = temp -> next;` and following code?

Comment: Erm, I assumed because theyre only NULL at the end of the list, which while traversing it is not NULL?

Comment: Ah I see. I add the clause `&& temp != NULL`, this fixed the seg fault, but im wondering if my method of inserting actually works?

Comment: When code "doesn't seem to be working" and code has "seg fault." testing pointers before de-referencing them is defensive coding and helps detect invalid assumptions.  Saves you time.  Consider  `assert()`

Comment: Id there still a problem to solve here?

Comment: I was just checking if my method i used for inserting a node would work, so i guess it does?